# Disabling empty DIV containers on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I want customize the look of mail.com interface on service.mail.com page by overriding CSS stylesheets in Firefox CSS, by adding userContent.css. The iframe loads the ads into divs. I blocked ads with firewall, but I can no get rid of spacing 160 x 600px which remains on page even if ads blocked. There is a multiple divs on the page, can no find which from them is parent element. Or perhaps, javascript involved too. I tried this CSS, but it not work.

```
@-moz-document domain(service.mail.com) {

#div-skyscraper_ad_container { display: none; }
#div-skyscraper  { display: none; }

}
```

Comment: why don't you install AdBlock Plus instead?

Comment: Most of these Firefox extensions installs adware, so I would prefer to avoid it. In addition, AdBlock can block ads, but it can not remove the empty DIVs.

Comment: Adblock Plus doesn't install adware. You can see for yourself in the source. Or at least I can. However, if you don't want to install extensions, you can locate the elements using firebug then try to modify the element's display style in the firebug style editor. Once you've found the right element and hidden it, add the style to your custom stylesheet.

Comment: I tried `Adblock Plus` and it's clean, you are right. Ads banner been removed, but it does not remove empty banner space anyway. I tried CSS code to disable every div and iframe element that I found there, but this not helps. OK, now it's better than it was before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually see that div on the page, but you may want to add !important to your css. It's possible that other css or script enabled styling is overriding your code.

Comment: Yes, its definitely possible that other CSS or script enabled styling override my code. Where exactly should be placed custom CSS in Firefox?